# Copy file from a folder to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I want to copy a file from a folder, one directory above the python script being interpreted, to a folder in the same directory the python script lives.

This is the folder structure.

```
-----/A
---------copyme.txt
-----/test
----------myCode.py
---------/B
```

I want to copy file `copyme.txt`, from folder `A`, to folder `B`, under the test folder.

This is the code i tried:

```
import os
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('../A/copyme.txt', '/B')
```

However, i received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile('../A/copyme.txt', 'B')
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'B'
```

Comment: yes, you copy a file to a directory, try a file to another file

Comment: Check this shutil.copyfile('../A/copyme.txt', '../B')

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) : it states *dst must be the complete target file name; look at copy() for a copy that accepts a target directory path. If src and dst specify the same file, SameFileError is raised.*
So if you want to copy with the same name just use `shutil.copy()` instead of `shutil.copyfile()`

Comment: @SauravRai I tried your approach, but it just copies the file to the parent folder of folder `A` and renames the filename as `B`.

Comment: @LuisBlanche I truied your code and i get `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/B'`

Comment: Well this is another problem then, this means your user does not have rights over that folder. If you are on a unix system you can fix that using `chmod` or `chown` commands if you have sudo rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current dir path and add the `src` path and `dest` path to it.

**Ex:**

```
import os
import shutil

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "..", "A", "copyme.txt"),
                os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "B", "copyme.txt"))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!